# Sum of n-th roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I'm being asked to prove that
$$1 + \omega + \omega^2 + ... + \omega^{n-1} = 0$$
where $\omega \ne 1$ is an n-th root of unity, and I don't know where to start

I feel like there's something terribly obvious that I'm missing here.

Comment: Geometric series.

Comment: Hint: sum of the first n terms of a geometric series

Comment: Do you know how to sum a finite geometric progression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^n-1=0$$
$$(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1)=0$$
Then, $x=1$ or $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1=0$.

The root of the second equation is what we denote by $\omega$.

Comment: this helped me greatly thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Hint : multiply by $\omega - 1 $

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $(1-w)$, then you will come up with an expression $1-w^n$, which must be zero.