# If $\omega = e^{(\frac{2\pi i}{n})}$ why $1+ \omega + \omega^{2} + ... + \omega^{n-1} = 0 $?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, summation, roots-of-unity

Let $\omega = e^{(\frac{2\pi i}{n})}$ why $1+ \omega + \omega^{2} + ... + \omega^{n-1} = 0 $?

I saw this on a algebra PPT slice. However the teacher did not explain why this equation is correct, can somebody show me some clue?

Thank you for your honest help!

Comment: Geometrically it is rather clear, and interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some explanation of this also in Wikipedia article on [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Summation). You can also find some further resources simply by googling for [sum of roots of unity is zero](http://google.com/search?q=sum+of+roots+of+unity+is+zero)

Geometrically, this corresponds to the fact that barycenter of regular $n$-gon is the center of escribed circle.

If you know [Viete's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula), you can also use the fact that these numbers are precisely the roots of the polynomial $x^n-1=0$. So their sum is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$, which is zero.

Having a look at some related posts could also help:

- [Intuitive understanding of why the sum of nth roots of unity is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38972/intuitive-understanding-of-why-the-sum-of-nth-roots-of-unity-is-0)
- [Proof that sum of complex unit roots is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891875/proof-that-sum-of-complex-unit-roots-is-zero)
- [Sum of n-th roots of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752660/sum-of-n-th-roots-of-unity)
- [Sum of nth roots of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122110/sum-of-nth-roots-of-unity)

(I have only noticed that one of similar posts has already been suggested as a duplicate after posting this answer. I have added it to this list for better visibility.)

Comment: Thank you martin. I speak poor english so I failed to search my question exhaustively, Thank you for your abundant solution.

Answer (score 9):

Note that $\omega^n=1$, so by summing the geometric series we get
$$ 1+\omega+\omega^2+\dots+\omega^{n-1}=\frac{1-\omega^n}{1-\omega}=0$$
as long as $n>1$.

Comment: Thank you carmichael. that's a very concise and beautiful answer!

Answer (score 7):

Assume $n>1$ (for $n=1$ this is not true).  Let $S=1+\omega+\omega^2+\dots+\omega^{n-1}$.  Then $$\omega S=\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\dots+\omega^n=\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\dots+1=S.$$
Since $\omega\neq 1$ (since $n>1$), this implies $S=0$.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I did not notice that N must be great than 1. your answer is beautiful.

Comment: @Eric: Hey Eric,  I would like to contact you via email. Can I request your email please?